# Redux Thunk Common Actions - Standalone + Combined

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Implementing the pattern Dan (@gaearon) demonstrated [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1676), I was just wondering the best way to have the common action work standalone in the following scenario:

```
const commonAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get('/resource');
      dispatch(success('SUCCESS', response.data));

    } catch(error) {
      dispatch(error('ERROR', error));
      throw error; //this is the problem
    }
}

const combinedAction = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    try {
      await dispatch(commonAction());
      const otherResponse = await api.get('/otherResource');

      dispatch(success('COMBINED_SUCCESS', otherResponse.data));

    } catch(error) {
      dispatch(error('COMBINED_ERROR', error));
    }
}
```

The above works in that if either fails, the `COMBINED_ERROR` will be dispatched, due to the `commonAction` re-throwing it's error. However, if I wanted to use `commonAction` by itself, I would get an Unhandled promise rejection error due to the re-throw.

One thought I had was an optional bool `isStandAlone = true` to determine whether to re-throw or not, i.e.

```
const commonAction = (isStandAlone = true) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.get('/resource');
      dispatch(success('SUCCESS', response.data));

    } catch(error) {
      dispatch(error('ERROR', error));

      if(!isStandAlone) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
}
```

And then in the `combinedAction` I would just:

```
await dispatch(commonAction(false));
```

Is this a code smell? Is there a better and/or different way to approach this?